# Can I Edit the Files Live With a Java EE Web Application?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am a Web programmer who uses PHP.  In PHP, I can connect via FTP via Dreamweaver
and start editing files live to test changes.

Now I am learning Java/Spring to make Web sites. I want to know is it possible that I can connect via FTP and change files like:

1. Change the variable name.
2. Hit save.
3. When I refresh the browser, then I see the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to configure a Servlet Container so that the application runs directly from the codebase.  You can also configure it to monitor class files and look for changes, as well as look for changes in JSP pages.

It's not recommended configuration for production servers, so it's best on a dev server or local server, but this will allow you to develop much more rapidly and avoid all the BS of having to build a new WAR file and redeploy and restart just for a simple 2 second change.

Each container is different, but here is a [FAQ on Configuring Tomcat for Development Mode](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing).

[Google App Engine's Eclipse Plug-in](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html) also sets you up with a development/debug mode.  Each change is recognized instantly, letting you focus on meeting your business goals instead of constantly stopping and starting the server.

As for editing "live" code, I hope you're not talking about code on a production server.  That's just not a recommended practice. Java EE is about engineering, reliable, secure, scalable, production systems.  Development is purposely kept separate from production because Java EE development typically involves much more complex problems and solutions than PHP Web sites, in general.

For instance, many banking websites use Java/EE technologies, and those developers never take risks, such as editing live code, that could breach the trust of their users or compromise their trust.

Comment: although it may not be recoomended but is it possible , because i have VPS server where i will host the website. but i have to show chnages to my client on daily basis , so i was thinking of working on that machine directly. rather than work locally and then upload new files. is it possible

Comment: @Pasha - If you configure Tomcat to run from the codebase, and configure it for development mode, then this is indeed possible.  I would forget that though as soon as you get a job working with real Java Engineers. They aren't going to like that!

Answer (score 0):

2 things.

1. Yes, you can change files like properties files, text files, xmls and images and whatnots
2. No, you cannot change JSPs / Servlets as they are compiled into byte codes.